# using Asynctask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to use async task  to load data from a URL  using  json array.

I would like pass a URL everytime I call the AsyncTask.

in this example i would like to call the AsyncTask in the info class
i would also like to display the value from the array in the text view.

I will greatly appreciate any help. thanks.

info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoTxtLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/InfoTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/InfoTxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

info.java

```
public class Info extends Activity {

TextView resultView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dbtext);
        new DB().execute();// calling async task
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Log_tag", "Error in opening Info page" + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("couldnt load info page");
    }
}
}
```

Result from browser

```
[{"client_id":"1","client_name":"client1"},{"client_id":"2","client_name":"client2"}]
```

db.java

```
public class DB extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
TextView resultView;
String result = "";
String s = "";
InputStream isr = null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/site/client.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Log_tag", "Error in Http connection" + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("couldnt connect to the database");
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
    }

    // parse the json data
    try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "ID :" + json.getInt("client_id") + "\n" + "NAME :"
                    + json.getString("client_name");

        }
        //resultView.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data" + e.toString());
    }
    return s;

}


protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    // showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    if (s!= null){
        resultView.setText(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can pass url to doInbackground() directly or to the constructor of the asynctask. like new DB(URL).execute(); pass the url to construcor and use the same in asynctask or new DB().execute(url); change the param doInbackground() to string to receive and use the same

Comment: you are already calling your AsyncTask from the Info class,  and it seems like your display the text using setText as you need to.  please tell us what is your problem, Do you have a crash ? or anything unwanted ?

Comment: What's the question here??

Answer (score 1):

In here :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {  //<<<<<< method argument is different 

    if (s!= null){
        resultView.setText(s);
    }
}
```

currently you are not overriding `onPostExecute` method from AsyncTask because `doInBackground` method return type is `String` but you are passing `Long` in `onPostExecute` parameter. so just put `@Override` before all methods which you are overriding from AsyncTask as:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  //<<<< change to String from Long

    if (s!= null){
        resultView.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i am now getting a NullPointerException on postExcecute. what have we missed?

Comment: @jackdaniels : use `resultView.setText(result);` instead of  `resultView.setText(s);` in postexecute